# How to compare a list of integers and then sort it ascending?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections, hashmap

I am learning how to sort and compare the dimension of squares in `ArrayList`. The dimension of the squares first ordered by length. If two squares have the same length, the squares requiring the shorter width should come first.

```
public class Square {
private int length;
private int width;

public Square(int length, int width) {
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
}
}

public class Dimension {
private int length;
private int width;
ArrayList<Square> Dimension = new ArrayList<>();

public void addSquare(int length, int width) {
    Dimension.add(new Square(length, width));
}

public void sortDimension() {
    Collections.sort(Dimension, (length, width) -> length.compareTo(width));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Square square;
    Dimension dimension = new Dimension();
    dimension.addSquare(10, 5);
    dimension.addSquare(8, 8);
    dimension.addSquare(10, 2);
    dimension.addSquare(12, 10);
    dimension.addSquare(8, 5);
    dimension.sortDimension();

    for(int i=0; i<Dimension.size();i++ ) {
        System.out.println(Dimension.get(i));
    }
}
}
```

I found the `Collections.sort(List, (obj1, obj2) -> obj1.compareTo(obj2))` on the internet, but it does not work on my code. The compiler says `cannot convert from Obj to int`.

I need your suggestion on this matter. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use the word `Dimension` everywhere, for the class, for naming variables, here are suggestions

   ```
   ArrayList<Square> dims = new ArrayList<>(); // for the class attribut

   Dimension value = new Dimension(); // in the main
   ```
2. When providind a custom `Comparator`, you get a pair of object and need to determine the first one, you don't get it's properties

   ```
   Collections.sort(dims, (o1, o2) -> ); // Both o1 and o2 are Square instances

   // You'd get for something like
   Collections.sort(dims, (o1, o2) -> o1.getLength() == o2.getLength() ?
                                      o1.getWidth() - o2.getWidth() :
                                      o1.getLength() - o2.getLength());
   ```
3. But you can use `Comparator` interface that provides nice methods

   ```
   dims.sort(Comparator.comparing(Square::getLength).thenComparing(Square::getWidth));
   ```

Then in the main to access the list you need to go from the instance, as `value.dims.size()`. And with a nice `toString` in `Square` class it' be ok

```java
class Square {
    private int length, width;
    public Square(int length, int width) {
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
    }
    public int getLength() {return length;}
    public int getWidth() {return width; }
    @Override
    public String toString() {return "Square{" + "length=" + length + ", width=" + width + '}';}
}

class Dimension {

    private ArrayList<Square> dims = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dimension value = new Dimension();
        value.addSquare(10, 5);
        value.addSquare(8, 8);
        value.addSquare(10, 2);
        value.addSquare(12, 10);
        value.addSquare(8, 5);
        value.sortDimension();

        for (int i = 0; i < value.dims.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(value.dims.get(i));
        }
    }

    public void addSquare(int length, int width) {
        dims.add(new Square(length, width));
    }
    public void sortDimension() {
        dims.sort(Comparator.comparing(Square::getLength).thenComparing(Square::getWidth));
    }
}
```